# d3.js scatter chart - clipping the sparklines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, clipping

I created a dynamic d3.js chart that plots time series.
Each second I add a new sample and remove an old sample.
It gives the impression that the sparklines are moving from the right to the left, which is good.
However, I am not very happy with the way the new and old segment of a path are added and removed.

See this picture:
[image]

On this image, you can see a little gap between the y-axis on the right and the sparklines. As the sparklines move to the left, this gap gets bigger and once it is large enough the new segments of the sparklines are then added. That doesn't look very smooth.
I would like the new segments to be drawn as the sparklines move to the left (like you would do when drawing it by hand).

I am using a clip-path to hide the part of paths that I don't want (outside of the plot), but that doesn't seem to give me the correct behavior.

Definition of the `clip-path`:

```
 this.container.append('defs')
  .append('clipPath')
    .attr('id', 'chart-content')
  .append('rect')
    .attr('height', this.height)
    .attr('width', this.width);
```

Use of the `clip-path`:

```
   group.path = this.paths
    .append('g')
      .attr('clip-path', 'url(#chart-content)')
    .append('path')
      .data([group.data])
```

On another note, the clip-path seem to work when I am panning and zooming.. Which confuse me even more! I hope someone can help me out with that!

Comment: Could you include a demo? Woud be easier with reproducible code.

Comment: @XavierGuihot, whilst trying to create a minimalist snippet I managed to fix my issue. See bellow!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question.. 
Here is a snippet of a dynamic line chart!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }
  #chart{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }
</style>
<div id='chart'></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};
  var padding = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 40};

  let width;
  let height;
  let svg;
  let container;
  let data;
  let xScale;
  let yScale;
  let now;
  let path;
  let gX;
  let xAxis;
  let lineGenerator;
  const duration = 500;

  render = () => {
    this.hostElement = d3.select('#chart');
    this.width = this.hostElement.node().getBoundingClientRect().width - this.margin.left - this.margin.right - this.padding.left - this.padding.right;
    this.height = this.hostElement.node().getBoundingClientRect().height - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom - this.padding.bottom - this.padding.top;

    this.createSvg();
    this.createAxis();
    this.createLine();
    this.defineBounds();
    this.tick();
  }

  createSvg = () => {
    this.svg = this.hostElement
      .append('svg')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.margin.left + ',' + this.margin.top + ')')
        .attr('width', this.width + this.padding.right + this.padding.left)
        .attr('height', this.height + this.padding.top + this.padding.bottom)

    this.container = this.svg
      .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'chart')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.padding.left + ',' + this.padding.top + ')')
        .attr('width', this.width)
        .attr('height', this.height);
  }

  createAxis = () => {
    // maxY
    const maxY = d3.max(this.data, d => d.value);

    // minX & maxX
    const minX = d3.min(this.data, d => d.date);
    const maxX = d3.max(this.data, d => d.date);
    this.now = maxX;
    const maxXToDisplay = moment(maxX).subtract(1, 's').toDate();
    const minXToDisplay = moment(minX).add(2, 's').toDate();

    // Update scales
    this.xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([minXToDisplay, maxXToDisplay])
      .range([0, this.width]);

    this.yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, maxY])
      .range([this.height, 0]);

    // Update axis
    this.xAxis = d3.axisBottom(this.xScale);
    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(this.yScale);

    // Draws the axis
    this.gX = this.container.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'x axis')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + this.height + ')')
      .call(this.xAxis);

    const gY = this.container.append('g')
      .attr('class', 'y axis')
      .call(yAxis);
  }

  createLine = () => {
    this.lineGenerator = d3.line()
      .x(d => this.xScale(d.date))
      .y(d => this.yScale(d.value))
      .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX);

    this.path = this.container
      .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'path-container')
        .attr('clip-path', 'url(#chart-content)')
      .append('path')
        .datum(this.data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr('d', this.lineGenerator);
  }

  tick = () => {
    this.now = moment(this.now).add(1, 's').toDate();

    // Add new values
    this.data.push({
      value: Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 15),
      date: this.now
    });

    // Remove old values
    this.data.shift();

    this.path.attr('d', this.lineGenerator);

    const numberSamplesToDisplay = this.data.length - 2;
    const minX = moment(this.now).subtract(numberSamplesToDisplay, 's').toDate();
    const maxX = this.now;
    const maxXToDisplay = moment(maxX).subtract(1, 's').toDate();
    const minXToDisplay = moment(minX).add(1, 's').toDate();

    // Shift domain
    this.xScale.domain([minXToDisplay, maxXToDisplay]);

    // Slide x-axis left
    const xTransition = this.gX.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .call(this.xAxis);

    // Slide paths left
    this.path.attr('transform', null)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + this.xScale(minX) + ', 0)')
      .on('end', this.tick);
  }

  defineBounds = () => {
    this.container.append('defs')
      .append('clipPath')
        .attr('id', 'chart-content')
      .append('rect')
        .attr('height', this.height)
        .attr('width', this.width);
  }

  generateData = () => {
    const dataset = [
      {
        value: Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 15),
        date: moment().subtract(60, 'seconds').toDate()
      }
    ];

    for (let i = 0; i < 59; i ++) {
      dataset.push({
        value: Math.floor(10 + Math.random() * 15),
        date: moment(dataset[dataset.length - 1].date).add(1, 'seconds').toDate()
      })
    }
    return dataset;
  }

  this.data = generateData();
  render();
</script>
```